# Compare multiple variables with a value in a single expression

Tags: ruby, variables

I have two variables `a` and `b`. I want to compare both `a` and `b` to a value, say `10`.

I can do it like this:

```
10 == a && 10 == b
```

But, I was wondering if there is any way to write it in a single expression? (E.g. like `a == b == 10`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[a,b,3].all? {|x| x==10}
```

but in this case

```
[].all? {|x| x==10}
```

will also return true

Comment: `list.empty? ? false : list.all? {|x| x == 10}` should take care of the empty issue.

Comment: Or `not(list.empty?) && list.all? {|x| x==10}`

Comment: +1 IMO, this is better than the accepted answer. And the edge case does not really matter for the question.

Comment: I like to use ['val1', 'val2'].include? x, but that's just me maybe.

Answer (score 4):

Updated, after comment from aztaroth:

```
[a,b].uniq == [10]
```

Comment: Don't do this. It significantly obscures the intent of the test. Simple and clear beats concise and obscure every time. The other answer using Array#all? is superior.